# MVC - where does this belong to?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

If I had something like this:

[image: Class diagram]

Where would each class go? Does anyone have any links to good examples of MVC?

Comment: What language are you programming in?

Comment: I'm using c# in Visual Studio 2010

Comment: Doesnt seem like a project for MVC, don't just force patterns into code

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Shape`, `Rectangle`, `Circle` and `Drawing` all have some data in them about the points that make them up, those classes are definitely `Model` classes. I'm not quite sure what `V1Drawing` and `V2Drawing` are, nor `DrawPackage1` or `DrawPackage2`, so I don't quite know where those would go.

That being said, the `draw()` methods on all of the classes are a bit out-of-place in an MVC world. The domain objects (the `Model` should not know anything about how their information is presented to the world (in general). For all a `Shape` knows, it might be being used by an ASCii-based graphics editor one minute, a "normal" graphics editor the next, and then (for our MVC-based web app) being presented to a browser that needs to have things drawn on it via javascript.

The power of MVC is that it lets you keep your domain objects loosely coupled to how they are presented. The `View` layer would contain various sorts of `Drawer` classes that could take shapes and, because it knows what's in the shapes and where it's "drawing" to, produces the correct sort of output.

Without knowing more, it's hard to take the architecture much farther, but in a nutshell, put data-oriented things that represent state and deal ONLY with that state (not external things) in the `Model` and put stuff that deals with how that state/data is *represented* in the `View`